# Utility of std::forward<Func> at call

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

I am coding functions like the well known *tuple_apply*, which take a rvalue reference of a Function as parameter. 
During my researches on the web, I came across the two following calls:

```
template <
    typename Func,
    /* stuff */
>
void myfunction(Func && func, /* stuff */)
{
    std::forward<Func>(func)(/* stuff */); // use of std::forward before call
    func(/* stuff */);                     // direct call
}
```

Is this call to `std::forward` really usefull ? If so why ?

Thanks for your enlightenment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most scenarios there are no difference between these two options. However, `Func` may have ref-qualified `operator()`. Like the following:

```
struct Func {
    operator()(/* stuff */) &&;
}
```

This can be called only on r-values, so the second call will not compile, since `func` inside `myfunction` is an l-value. Or it can have ref-qualified overloads:

```
struct Func {
    operator()(/* stuff */) &;
    operator()(/* stuff */) &&;
}
```

In this case call without `std::forward` will use the first overload regardless of what is passed to `myfunction`: an l-value or an r-value. A call with `std::forward`, on the other side, will pick appropriate overload based on l-valueness of the passed `func` object.

Comment: I undertand. Thank you Mikhail :)